# How do I run a cron job that spawns a tmux session? (MacOS)

Tags: bash, cron, tmux, macos-catalina

I'm on MacOS Catalina. I'm trying to run a cron job that spawns a named tmux session with windows. Here is the `crontab -l`:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/dev/project; ./start.sh; ./poll 2>> /tmp/cron.out
```

However I don't see my session with `tmux ls`. In my error logs `cat /tmp/cron.out`

```
./poll: line 3: tmux: command not found
./poll: line 5: tmux: command not found
```

This is the script I'm running. I have tmux installed for my user, and it works normally. When I execute `poll` normally, it works just fine.

Here is `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux kill-session -t collect

tmux new -s "collect" -d ./stuff
```

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). This page is dedicated to questions about software development.

Comment: Try using the full tmux path: `/usr/local/bin/tmux kill-session ...`

Comment: @0stone0 that worked. The cron user is the same as my local user (verified with `whoami`). Why doesn't the cron job have `/usr/local/bin/` in its path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `tmux` in your regular terminal, it will search the `$PATH` variable to find the correct folder.

Scripts that get executed by `cron` does not share the same environment `$PATH` variable as your user, therefore the script can't find the exatuable.

You could add the `$PATH` to you script, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/bin

tmux kill-session -t collect

tmux new -s "collect" -d ./stuff
```

But I guess using the full path is in your case much more readable!

Read more about `$PATH` on [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)